# Unable to get the checkbox selected or not in template driven form (angular 7)

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, ngmodel

```
  <input type="checkbox" [name]="filter.filterName" ngModel />
```

let filterValue: string = testForm.form.value[filter.filterName];

filterValue is always returning empty string checkbox when checked and unchecked

how can i know that checkbox is checked or not in template driven form and no data binding. I need value from testForm:NgForm object ?

Comment: It should work. Please double check whether `filter.filterName` in `template` and `controller` keep the same value. See [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i know that checkbox is checked or not in template driven form and no data binding.

You can use template variable.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" #check />
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('check')
check: ElementRef;
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udaej4

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your example works. 
But fails to work when angular form comes into picture. can you check the below url
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmnefx

Comment: @JayaVenkat It's data binding issue. checkbox isn't bound because of `[type]="filter.fieldType"`. try `type="checkbox"`. It would work and there's no problem since your ngSwitch applied on `div` tags.